# Cannot distinguish dynamic elements while webscraping with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I'm trying to write a bot for an online survey, but I'm stuck at one particular page.

It contains a list of checkboxes, that are distinguishable only by the id parameter like so:

```
//*[@id="prompt_368243"]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/label/div/div
//*[@id="prompt_368241"]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/label/div/div
//*[@id="prompt_368228"]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/label/div/div
```

(screenshot link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TBpI4.jpg)

The situation is the same when checking cs-selectors. What I've been using since the problem occured was something like:

```py
choice = '//*[starts-with(@id,\'prompt\')]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[' + str(randint(1, 3)) + ']/span'
```

Is there a way to pick each row separately knowing that the id value is changing each time the survey is being loaded? I noticed that the number is decreasing with every row, however it is not a constant value or anything. The objects do not have any label to them which is problematical as well.

Comment: The XPath style you are using will not work very well for this scenario. You need to write a dynamic path involving something like `//div[text()='someText']/label[text()='someLabel']/div/div`. If you post the HTML for the page you are working on (not just a screenshot), we can help you get started.

Comment: @Christine thank you for your reply, however I need to wait until this survey is available again to get the html, the issues are coming one after another